# Run LESS in Codepen.io

Tags: css, less

I am trying to run LESS in Codepan.io.
Here is the link to my code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zhLjI
I just wrote this line of code

```
.user {
  .rotate(90deg);
}
```

but I get the following error from the server

```
757: unexpected token at 'Internal Server Error'
```

Any idea why my code does not work?
Thanks

Comment: I would recommend using Sass (with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/), included on Codepen) if you want to use a bunch of prebuilt mixins. For example. Compass has [`+transform(rotate(90deg))`](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transform/) which will take care of your vendor prefixes for you.

Answer (score 2):

You have to define the `.rotate` mixin.

```
.rotate(@deg){
  -webkit-transform: rotate(@deg);

}
.user {
  .rotate(90deg);
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/bookcasey/pen/aDFdy)

Comment: +1, yes, your demo works. anyway in my project I use to write just . `th {
    .rotate(90deg);
}`and it works.